# Find point in dataframe where (col_1[ i ], col_2[ i ]) = (col_1[ j ], -col_2[ j ])

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

There might be an obvious solution to this that I have missed but here goes:

Consider the data frame below. I wish to create a column with TRUE/FALSE values, where the value is TRUE whenever the condition (col_1[i], col_2[i]) = (col_1[j], -col_2[j]) is fulfilled. Note that sum() does not work here, since there might be a third value.
To elaborate; what I have is:

```
col_1 <- c("x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z")
col_2 <- c(-1, 1, 3, -3, 4, 7, 3)
df <- data.frame(col_1, col_2)
```

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

I think the answer must be something with df %>% group_by(x), but I can't think of the complete solution.

Comment: Its unclear to me what you are asking, what are x and a in this??

Comment: You need to specify the values of x,y,z first then we will be able to answer

Comment: Sorry! Made some editing, hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt. As you were saying, grouping data is necessary. I defined groups with col_1 and foo. foo contains absolute values of col_2. If the number of observation is larger than one and unique number of observation in col_2 is equal to 2, you have the pairs you are searching.

```
group_by(df, col_1, foo = abs(col_2)) %>% 
mutate(check = n() > 1 & n_distinct(col_2) == 2) %>% 
ungroup %>% 
select(-foo)

  col_1 col_2 check
  <fct> <dbl> <lgl>
1 x        -1 TRUE 
2 x         1 TRUE 
3 y         3 TRUE 
4 y        -3 TRUE 
5 y         4 FALSE
6 z         7 FALSE
7 z         3 FALSE
```

As Ronak previously mentioned, there may be cases like this.

```
col_1 <- c("x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z")
col_2 <- c(1, 1, 3, -3, 4, 7, 3) 
df2 <- data.frame(col_1, col_2)

  col_1 col_2
1     x     1
2     x     1
3     y     3
4     y    -3
5     y     4
6     z     7
7     z     3

group_by(df2, col_1, foo = abs(col_2)) %>% 
mutate(check = n() > 1 & n_distinct(col_2) == 2) %>% 
ungroup %>% 
select(-foo)

  col_1 col_2 check
  <fct> <dbl> <lgl>
1 x         1 FALSE
2 x         1 FALSE
3 y         3 TRUE 
4 y        -3 TRUE 
5 y         4 FALSE
6 z         7 FALSE
7 z         3 FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer. This was just what I needed and you solved a big headache for me. Thanks again! :D

Comment: @SofieAbildgaard I am glad to hear that this helped you. Good luck with your work.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. Perfect.

Comment: @RonakShah You brought up a very good point. I was initially blind to it. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following base R code, where a custom function `f` is defined to check the sum:

```
f <- function(v) {
  unique(c(combn(seq(v),2)[,combn(v,2,sum)==0]))
}

dfout <- Reduce(rbind,
                lapply(split(df,df$col_1), 
                       function(v) {
                         v$col_3 <- F
                         v$col_3[f(v$col_2)] <- T
                         v
                       })
)

dfout <- dfout[order(as.numeric(rownames(dfout))),]
```

such that

```
> dfout
  col_1 col_2 col_3
1     x    -1  TRUE
2     x     1  TRUE
3     y     3  TRUE
4     y    -3  TRUE
5     y     4 FALSE
6     z     7 FALSE
7     z     3 FALSE
```